Somebody is wrong on the internet…
I'm currently at Scaling Bitcoin in the "Scaling Community Workshop".
One of the points that has come up as a potential solution for improving online discourse is "Fact-Checking".
Do you think that Bitcoin.Stackexchange.com could be a good platform for this sort of information?
Discuss!

Fact checking on what exactly?

Evidence people are sourcing for their discussion contributions.

I think it's fine to ask questions like "Is it true that...?", if you want evidence to confirm or refute some claim.  But with the usual caveats:

Volume: Please try not to ask a gigantic number of questions in a short time.  Prioritize those that are of broad interest, or have unusual features that need specific expertise; don't just ask a question for every single thing that anyone says.
Justification: Give some explanation as to why the question is interesting, and/or who claimed it was true.  
Research effort: Make a reasonable attempt to answer the question for yourself first.  If you don't find the answer, then you can ask here, but include a summary of what you already tried, to save time for potential answerers.  (If you do find the answer, then you could post a question with answer, if you think it is something that will be of interest to others.)
Standards: Try to make it clear what kind of evidence you would like answers to include.  An expert's opinion?  Blog posts?  Peer-reviewed articles?  References to source code?  This will avoid answerers being frustrated when they work hard on something that isn't what you were looking for.

